# Row reducing over different fields

Tags: linear-algebra

Q:

[image: mathq]![mathq]

I've done i), however I'm confused on how to do ii)

My lecture defined $\mathbb{F}_2$ to be the field with two elements, (0,1) - however I'm not sure on how to answer the question.

To find a basis for ker(T_a) and Im(T_a) we were taught to row reduce the matrix first, should I change every element while reducing the matrix? e.g. should I change -1 to 1 while reducing the matrix? Or should I just use the current basis for the kernal and the image and just change all the elements in that to elements in $\mathbb{F}_2$? Finally, my last question is how would I change negative numbers? We were never taught about modular arithmitic but I have read a little about it and it seems that every element not in field 2 I can reduce to elements in field 2 but doing modulo 1, but how would it work with negative numbers?

I apologise for all the questions, I really have no idea how to proceed else I wouldn't ask.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot interpret a matrix as a linear map over a field$~F$ unless the matrix entries lie in$~F$; normally that would mean that you cannot interpret the given matrix with the entries it has (which are not elements of$\def\F{~\Bbb F_2}\F$) as linear map over$~\F$. But there is a special convention in ring theory that integers can always be used to designate elements of a ring, by taking for instance $3$ to stand for $1+1+1$, and evaluating that in the ring. For $\F$ this means that all even numbers are interpreted as$~0$ and all odd entries as$~1$.

Once one has obtained a matrix with entries in$~F$, reducing the matrix to echelon form proceeds in the usual way, but doing all arithmetic in$~F$ (so modulo$~2$ in case $F=\F$). Actually this is quite easy for$~\F$, since on never needs to divide by a coefficient: the only nonzero coefficient possible is$~1$.